# How to implement Firebase phone authentication with Ionic 4?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

Is it possible to use phone authentication with Firebase and Ionic 4 in mobile apps?

I have seen some old tutorials implementing phone authorization with Ionic 3, but these seem to be outdated.

The firebaseui-web project does not support phone authentication for [cordova apps](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web#cordova-setup), but I am unsure if that implies that Firebase phone authentication is impossible with ionic apps.

If you cannot use Firebase's phone authentication with Ionic 4, is there an alternative phone authentication service that does work with Ionic 4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it with Firebase's Javascript SDK, it will need the user to pass a CAPTCHA and then send the phone number a verification code which you can login and auth with, the process is explained here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone

Comment: I believe this does not work when building a mobile app with ionic because the CAPTCHA breaks.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: I have not found a premade solution. The best solution I have found is to create server endpoints or cloud functions to do the phone verification yourself (using Twilio to send the confirmation text) and then login the user with the server side Firebase admin api.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the firebase auth sms service will only send messages when the app is in production mode (uploaded to the store). But to be able to test the methods from test mode, it is adding a test number in the white list of firebase.

In my case, I try these:

**sms-verification.page.ts**

```
sendSmsVerification(phoneNumber): Promise <firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
        var verificationId;
        var code;
        const timeOutDuration = 60;
        const tell = '+54' + phoneNumber;
        this.FireBase.verifyPhoneNumber(tell, timeOutDuration).then(async (credential) => {
            // alert(credential.instantVerification);
            if (credential.verificationId) {
                console.log("Android credential: ", credential);
                verificationId = credential.verificationId;
            } else {
                console.log("iOS credential: ", credential);
                verificationId = credential;
            }
            if (credential.instantVerification) {
                code = credential.code;
                this.verifySms(verificationId, code)
                .then( resp => {
                    resolve(resp);
                })
                .catch( err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            } else {
                let prompt = await this.alertCtrl.create({
                    backdropDismiss: false,
                    header: 'Ingrese el codigo de confirmación del SMS.',
                    inputs: [{ name: 'confirmationCode', placeholder: 'Código de confirmación' }],
                    buttons: [
                        { text: 'Cancelar',
                        handler: data => { 
                            console.log('Cancel clicked');
                            resolve(data);
                        }
                        },
                        { text: 'Verificar',
                        handler: data => {
                            code = data.confirmationCode; 
                            this.verifySms(verificationId,code)
                            .then( resp => {
                                resolve(resp);
                            })
                            .catch( err => {
                                reject(err);
                            });                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
                prompt.present();
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Error! Catch SMSVerificacion', error);
            reject(error);
        });
    })
}


verifySms(verificationId, code): Promise <any> {
    console.log('parametros de verifySms ', verificationId +' ', code);
    const signInCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,code);
    return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(signInCredential);
}
```

Comment: What is -- this.Firebase here?

Comment: this is dependency injection of the FirebaseX. 
    
import { FirebaseX } from '@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx';

constructor(
    public FireBase: FirebaseX
) { }

Comment: Hi @jeronimoscarpalabrador, if `credential.instantVerification` the credential returned does not contain `code` field but `id`.

I'm looking for a way to mix native and js firebase for phone authentication but at the moment I don't have a solution to handle instantVerification. [Dave Alden, who maintains FirebaseX Cordova plugin think that should not work](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/435#issuecomment-646477846)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use firebase phone authentication using Cordova plugin,

[cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication)

Add this plugin to your ionic 4 project

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication --save
```

With this we can verify phone without using reCaptcha. 
Note that this only work on real android device, not emulator or browser.
Function implementation

```
verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, timeout)

cordova.plugins.firebase.auth.verifyPhoneNumber("+123456789", 30000)
.then(function(verificationId) {
        // pass verificationId to signInWithVerificationId
});
```

or 
[AngularFire](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firebase-phone-authentication-with-angular-4-tutorial/) (With reCaptcha)

https://github.com/angular/angularfire

First, install angularfire lib into your project

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
```

then import this lib into your class

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

code example:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber,recaptchaVerifier)
        .then(confirmationResult => {
          this.windowRef.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    })
```

Comment: Please try to write the content of the links in your answer, while a link only answer may be valid it is not recommended since it will be lost if the links go offline

Comment: Not working for me, I get terror verifyPhoneNumeber(...).then() is not a function